# How to reuse common parts of a long but similar native query in spring boot JPA repositories?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

In my Repository interface I have 2 similar aggregate queries which only differs on the group by column,

```
@Query(value = "select table1.a1, sum(table2.b), sum(table2.c) from table2" 
+ " join table1 on table2.table1_id = table1.id group by table1.a1", nativeQuery = true)
public List<FooDTO> getAggregateSumWithGroupByA1();

@Query(value = "select table1.a2, sum(table2.b), sum(table2.c) from table2"
 + " join table1 on table2.table1_id = table1.id group by table1.a2", nativeQuery = true)
public List<FooDTO> getAggregateSumWithGroupByA2();
```

Instead of repeating the common parts of the 2 queries I want to achieve something like this:

```
String myGroupByQuery = "select table1.%s, sum(table2.b), sum(table2.c) from table2"
        + " join table1 on table2.table1_id = table1.id group by table1.%s";

@Query(value = StringFormat.format(myGroupByQuery, "a1"), nativeQuery = true)
public List<FooDTO> getAggregateSumWithGroupByA1();

@Query(value = StringFormat.format(myGroupByQuery, "a2"), nativeQuery = true)
public List<FooDTO> getAggregateSumWithGroupByA2();
```

Ofcourse the above code shows error: `The value for annotation attribute Query.value must be a constant expression` Any way to do it, or any other suggestions to achieve something similar? Thank you.

Searched all over but found no solutions that fulfill my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You might try using Spring Dynamic JPA library (https://github.com/joutvhu/spring-dynamic-jpa). Instead of having two methods, keep only one, and pass the "group by" criteria as a String argument.

Comment: neat library! but I was hoping to find something provided by spring boot to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You were nearly there, try a constant, ie:

```
public static String MY_GROUP_BY_QUERY = "select table1.%s, sum(table2.b), sum(table2.c) from table2"
        + " join table1 on table2.table1_id = table1.id group by table1.";

@Query(value = MY_GROUP_BY_QUERY + "a1", nativeQuery = true)
public List<FooDTO> getAggregateSumWithGroupByA1();

@Query(value = MY_GROUP_BY_QUERY + "a2", nativeQuery = true)
public List<FooDTO> getAggregateSumWithGroupByA2();
```

Comment: "table1.%s" I need to put "a1" in place of %s here too.

Comment: Your question was about 'reusing the common parts". I have answered that. Replacing the '%s' is standard JPA. Use ':s' and https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query  to substitute a named parameter - section 6.2